# How to make "NativeScript Collapsing Header Plugin" work with Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is there a way to make "NativeScript Collapsing Header Plugin" (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-collapsing-header) work with NativeScript-Angular?

I have tried importing into app.component.ts using:

```
registerElement("CollapsingHeader", () => require("nativescript-collapsing-header").CollapsingHeader);
```

Tried to display it in home.component.html

```
<GridLayout class="page page-content">
    <PullToRefresh (refresh)="refreshList($event)">
        <collapsingHeader:CollapsingHeader>
            <collapsingHeader:Header class="header-template">
                <Label id="headerLabel" text="Collapsing Header Text"></Label>
            </collapsingHeader:Header>
            <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
                <ng-template let-item="item">
                    <Label [nsRouterLink]="['../item', item.id]" [text]="item.name" class="list-group-item"></Label>
                </ng-template>
            </ListView>
        </collapsingHeader:CollapsingHeader>
    </PullToRefresh>
</GridLayout>
```

Getting this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Expecting a valid View instance.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have registered the `CollapsingHeader` view exposed by the plugin properly but you are using the NativeScript Core syntax in your HTML template.

Instead of `<collapsingHeader:CollapsingHeader>` try `<CollapsingHeader>` which matches your first parameter to `registerElement`.

Also you might have to register the header component, before using it in your HTML

```
registerElement("Header", () => require("nativescript-collapsing-header").Header);
```

and use it as `<Header>` in your HTML.

Comment: Added `registerElement("Header", () => require("nativescript-collapsing-header").Header);` and used `<CollapsingHeader>
            <Header class="header-template">
                <Label id="headerLabel" text="Collapsing Header"></Label>
            </Header>
            <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
                ....
            </ListView>
        </CollapsingHeader>` but still getting same error.

Comment: I just had a look at the code, looks like the plugin is not compatible with any recent version of NativeScript, there are issues reported it doesn't even work with {N} v4.x. But fortunately the plugin doesn't do anything more than putting layouts / views together which you can do in your project by your own.